# Stop expanding UITableView from reloading contents incorrectly - Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, swift3

I have a UITableView that expands when a particular cell is tapped. My problem is that on first load or expand of the table the additional cells load the contents correctly but with successive closing and expanding of the table things load incorrectly.

**My code:**

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {


    let currentCellDescriptor = getCellDescriptorForIndexPath(indexPath)
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: currentCellDescriptor["cellIdentifier"] as! String, for: indexPath) as! CustomCell

        if currentCellDescriptor["cellIdentifier"] as! String == "idCellTextfield" {

        cell.photo.image = globalVariable.images2[(indexPath as NSIndexPath).row]
        cell.name.text = globalVariable.names2[(indexPath as NSIndexPath).row]
        cell.price.text = globalVariable.prices2[(indexPath as NSIndexPath).row]
        cell.unitPrice.text = globalVariable.unitPrice2[(indexPath as NSIndexPath).row]
        cell.pPrice.text = globalVariable.previousPrice2[(indexPath as NSIndexPath).row]


            //This is the portion of code that loads incorrectly
            //This code identifies if an item is on special (true or false) and if it is adds a border to the left of the cell, specifies saving amount and changes the colour and style of some labels.

        if globalVariable.specialBool2[(indexPath as NSIndexPath).row] == true {

            let attributeString: NSMutableAttributedString =  NSMutableAttributedString(string: globalVariable.previousPrice2[(indexPath as NSIndexPath).row])
            attributeString.addAttribute(NSStrikethroughStyleAttributeName, value: 2, range: NSMakeRange(0, attributeString.length))
            cell.pPrice.attributedText = attributeString;

            cell.price.textColor = UIColor(red: 214/255, green: 14/255, blue: 0/255, alpha: 1.0)

            cell.layer.addBorderWatchlist(UIRectEdge.left, color: UIColor(red: 214/255, green: 14/255, blue: 0/255, alpha: 1.0), thickness: 6)

            cell.savingAmount.text = globalVariable.savingAmount2[(indexPath as NSIndexPath).row]

        } else if globalVariable.specialBool2[(indexPath as NSIndexPath).row] == false  {
            cell.pPrice.text = " "
            cell.savingAmount.text = " "
            cell.savingLbl.isHidden = true
            cell.savingAmount.isHidden = true
        }
        }

    cell.delegate = self

    return cell
}
```

What do I have to change in the relevant portion of code to ensure that the contents reloads correctly each time the table is expanded?

Comment: From this part of the code alone, I noticed that there is no consideration for if the currentCellDescriptor["cellIdentifier"] != "idCellTextfield" and I am not sure how you populate/mutate the globalVariable but assuming there is no changes, by using indexPath.row, once a cell expands you will be reading another data into each cell pushed down(larger index).

Comment: Also the indentation for the specialBool2 checks are off, please fix it. Adding in the codes for expanding/collapsing the cells might help find the full problem.

Comment: @BenOng Thanks for looking at my problem. Could you please expand on what I should do. I'm still learning swift.

Comment: By the current logic, I presume that you'd have a visibleCells array to determine have many cells are visible for the expanding logic. If you post the codes to determine visibleCells and your cellDescriptor, there might be some mistake there that caused the error